# Why does an unused CTE in Oracle cause an error in only one of these two cases?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a series of CTE's that I used in order to get the query results that I want, and they work as expected. However, as I started testing some separate queries (not related to the existing CTE's) that I hoped to add to the CTE list for later reference, I started getting an error. I can understand if an error is thrown whenever a CTE doesn't get used, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
  WITH 
  submissions_per_hacker AS(
    SELECT
      submission_date,
      COUNT(submission_id) AS submission_count,
      hacker_id
    FROM
      submissions
    GROUP BY
      submission_date,
      hacker_id
    ORDER BY
      submission_date ASC
  ),
  most_submissions AS(
    SELECT
      submission_date,
      MAX(submission_count) AS max_submissions
    FROM
      submissions_per_hacker
    GROUP BY
      submission_date
  ),
  best_hackers AS(
    SELECT
      most_submissions.submission_date AS the_date,
      most_submissions.max_submissions AS submissions,
      MIN(submissions_per_hacker.hacker_id) AS hacker_id
    FROM
      most_submissions
    INNER JOIN submissions_per_hacker ON 
      submissions_per_hacker.submission_count = most_submissions.max_submissions AND
      submissions_per_hacker.submission_date = most_submissions.submission_date
    GROUP BY
      most_submissions.submission_date,
      most_submissions.max_submissions
    ORDER BY
      the_date
  ),
  daily_best AS(
    SELECT
      best_hackers.the_date AS the_date,
      best_hackers.hacker_id AS ID,
      hackers.name AS name
    FROM
      best_hackers
    INNER JOIN hackers ON hackers.hacker_id = best_hackers.hacker_id
    ORDER BY
      the_date
  )
```

These work as expected, but I hoped to join the last CTE with another query that I am still writing. If I add the following query after the CTE's, there is no error:

```
  SELECT
    hackers.hacker_id,
    submissions.submission_date
  FROM
    submissions
  INNER JOIN
    hackers ON hackers.hacker_id = submissions.hacker_id
  ORDER BY
    hackers.hacker_id ASC,
    submissions.submission_date ASC
;
```

However, the following query does give an error:

```
  SELECT
    hacker_id,
    submission_date
  FROM
    submissions
  ORDER BY
    hacker_id ASC,
    submission_date ASC
;
```

Note that neither query uses any of the CTE's. Obviously I can just comment out all the CTE's while writing the rest of my code and then un-comment them when I am ready to use them, but I would like to understand why this behavior is happening in the first place.

Edit:
I accidentally copied two versions of the same code. This has been fixed.
The tables 'hackers' and 'submissions' are provided by the problem (this is from an online challenge problem) and the error that gets thrown in the latter case is:

ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel 
Process ID: 11698 
Session ID: 174 Serial number: 6767

The only difference between the two queries is that one contains an INNER JOIN, but neither references the CTE's.

Comment: The last two queries look identical and both are invalid as neither selects from a table named or aliased as hackers, yet references hackers.hacker_id in both the projection and order by sections.  Is hackers a local record variable?

Comment: A CTE that is defined but not used does **not** cause an error. Please show exactly what error you are getting if you need more help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error that's generated. Thanks.

Comment: @mathguy I'm guessing this is "ORA-32035: unreferenced query name defined in WITH clause".  But that error doesn't happen in 11g or 12c anymore.

Comment: @JonHeller - I stand corrected. I had no idea. I learned Oracle on version 11.2; I've heard about many features (and errors) of older versions, but this is the first time I heard of this issue. I assume (expect) that the SQL Standard never required that a factored subquery actually be used in a higher-level query or subquery, and that was just an Oracle feature... either way, good thing Oracle 11+ does the logical thing! Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Sentinel : my apologies. I accidentally copied the same snippet of code twice. I have corrected the mistake.

Comment: @BrentUnderwood ORA-03113 is a generic error message that usually means there was an Oracle bug that crashed the server process.  Look in the alert log for an error like ORA-600 or ORA-7445.  That's the real error message, and sometimes the first code in square brackets will point to a specific bug on My Oracle Support or Google.